# Iterate through array from NEWS API inside HTML mail from Sendgrid - NEXT.js

Tags: next.js, handlebars.js, html-email, sendgrid

I'm trying to iterate through array I'm receiving from NEWS API, inside HTML email, inside NEXT.js app which will be triggered when you point to specific URL inside app: "http://localhost:3000/api/mail"

Found out that you can use Handlebars syntax for it but it's not working for me.

Anyway I need to make a list of couple URLs, inside

tags, provided inside JSON file received as fetch from a custom query. Mail was sent successfully, but the content is not right.

Here is the code, hope someone can help.

```
import sendgrid from "@sendgrid/mail";

sendgrid.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

export const sendLatestNewsEmail = async () => {

    const apiResponse = await fetch(
        `https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?from=2023-02-08&to=2023-02-09&sortBy=popularity`,
        {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NEWS_KEY}`,
            },
        }
    );

    const json = await apiResponse.json();
    const { articles } = json;

    console.log(articles);

    // const articlesMail = [];

    // articles.map(({ url }) => {
    //    console.log(url);
    //    articlesMail.push(url);
    // })

    const msg = {
        to: "myemail@gmail.com", // Your email where you'll receive emails
        from: "myemail@gmail.com", // your website email address here
        subject: `news app v2`,
        html: `{{#if articles}}
                    <ul>
                    {{#each articles.url}}
                    <li>{{this.url}}</li>
                    {{/each}}
                    </ul>
                {{/if}}`,
    }

    sendgrid
        .send(msg)
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Email sent')
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error)
        })
};

export default sendLatestNewsEmail;
```

I tried Handlebars #each, but only solution to work is to put ${{articles}} inside HTML, but all URLs are joined as one, not on a separate lines.

Comment: You can't `#each` over `articles.url` if articles is an array and doesn't have a `url` property. The correct code would be: `{{#each articles as |url|}}<li>{{url}}</li>{{/each}}`.

Comment: Thank you @76484, I found another solution in the meantime, defining and populating HTML code block variable before the sending email process, and passing that var to a msg/html const. `articlesMail.forEach(printNewsUrls);

    function printNewsUrls(value) {
        codeBlock += " <br>" + value + "<br>"; 
      }`